# How to insert Gallery shortcode to a meta box

Tags: metabox, gallery

When we create a Image Gallery from the Media Modal Box and click on "Insert Gallery" button, the gallery shortcode is added to the main text area.

Is there a way to detect which Post Format is selected, and if its "Gallery" then is there a way to modify the action of the "Insert Gallery" button to add the shortcode to a meta box instead of the text area.

Answer (score 1):

That is a weird way to do it, shortcodes are really meant for inserting into the editor, if you want to program some functionality it's better to go straight into the template/code itself.

```
//check if post format is gallery type
if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');
}
```

Comment: I am actually trying to make this work for WordPress 3.6. Currently we need to first create a gallery which is then added to the Editor from where we have to copy paste it in the Gallery Meta Box. So I was trying to find a directly way to simply add some event to the "Insert gallery" button which could add the Gallery short code in the custom meta box.

Comment: The direct and better way is to do at at the template level, thus my answer.

Comment: We are still working on the post formats UI for 3.6, which as I keep reminding you, is in active development. There is no chance it will remain a bare field for the final release. If you'd like to donate your time to making this work in core, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @helen, yes am aware of it, I just asked the question as I wanted to implement it in my current theme irrespective of whether it would be implemented in final WP 3.6. I have been able to create something basic but still lot of bugs. Once done will share it on WP trac